# Page by Selenium webdriver closing, what should I do?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm trying to build an automation for LinkedIn. The app should go to the LinkedIn login page and enter the e-mail and password. That part is working, however, the window always closes by itself after some seconds.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from time import sleep

# link: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/feed/')
sleep(30)
# login 
email = ''
password = ''
box_email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@placeholder="Email or phone number"]')
box_email.send_keys(email)
box_password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@id="password"]')
sleep(2)
box_password.send_keys(password)
button_login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@id="join-form-submit"]')
sleep(1)
button_login.click
```

I already tried to download an updated version of chrome webdriver but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the browser to not close after the end of test script execution, then you need to add below line to the code:

```
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Try to change your code as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/feed/')
```